# How to switch to a new Activity not by position, but by _id in the table sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, onitemclicklistener

> Hello. There is a table from which data is displayed in ListView by position. Everything works great. But if there are spaces in the table, then this becomes a problem. How can I switch to the desired activity by _id in the table, and not by position?
>   I ask for help, I will be very grateful.
>   Thank you all very much!
>   Below is my code:
>
> This is my code MainActivity.java

```
this.listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
    databaseAccess.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotes);
    this.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if(id==0){
                Intent myintent = new 
    Intent(view.getContext(),MosObl.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,0);
            }
            if(id==1){
                Intent myintent = new 
    Intent(view.getContext(),Arhangelsk.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,1);
            }
            if(id==2){
                Intent myintent = new 
    Intent(view.getContext(),Astrahan.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,2);
            }
```

> This is my code DatabasesAccess.java

```
public List<String> getQuotes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM regiones where izbrannoe = 1", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the position of the clicked item (which is the only thing you will be able to get directly), you can get the quote from your list "quotes", using :

```
final String desiredQuote = quotes.get(position);
```

Then, making a request to your database you'll be able to get the desired id. Something like:

```
final Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM regiones where izbrannoe = 1 AND quote=?",new String [] {desiredQuote});
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I'm new to programming, I still can’t get anything. Could you explain in more detail with code elements how to do this? Sorry for the impudence.

Comment: In your `onItemClick` method, which is called everytime an item of your list is clicked, you have the `position`orgument, which is the position of the clicked item in your ListView.
With this position, your can get the String from your `list` ArrayList. it should be in the same position.
Then you'll just have to query your database to get the `_id`corresponding to this String in your database, assuming each String in your database is unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot, good idea. Could you help with the code, because my head is already not working and nothing works. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It may be difficult as I don't know your database nor your application... :/

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem...

Comment: How to get String from position?

Comment: Thank. Happened. How to get _id from the database?

Comment: Please read my answer... The second line I typed is a way to get the _id field, depending on your database structure...